# Проблема с извлечением архива tar.gz

Tags: linux

Проблема в следующем. 
Есть три tar.gz архива с данными. Один из них извлекается без проблем, остальные нет.

Начал разбираться, в чём дело. При вводе команды file 
на нормальном архиве, который распаковывается без проблем, выдаёт следующее:

```
file wav_data.aa.tar.gz 
wav_data.aa.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Tue Aug 25 12:38:40 2015, from Unix
```

т.е. все нормально.

Если смотрю информацию по другому файлу (проблемному), то

```
file wav_data.ab.tar.gz 
wav_data.ab.tar.gz: data
```

Как решить проблему? Данные целые,скачаны с репозитория Стенфорда.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что данные целые? Вы сравнивали их контрольные суммы после скачивания с известными? Можете дать ссылку на страницу откуда их скачивали? Вы уверены что это разные архивы, а не несколько частей одного? Если сделать `cat wav_data*.tar.gz > wav_data.tar.gz; tar -xzf wav_data.tar.gz` - будет ли успешный результат?

Comment: @МАН69К, [ссылка на базу](http://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/handle/10283/853). Результат по описанной вами технологии без успеха

Comment: там есть инструкция, как правильно распаковывать. Пробовали?

Comment: судя по именованию (aa, ab) - очень похоже на результат работы split, в этом случае это просто разделенный архив, и MAH69K все верно написал

Comment: С близкой к единице вероятностью MAH69K написал правильную команду, что значит «результат без успеха»?

Comment: @МАН69К, запуск `rsync` обычно решает этот вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

там же приложена [инструкция по распаковке этих файлов](http://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/853/ExtractionInstructions.txt?sequence=13&isAllowed=y):

```
$ cat wav_data.*.tar.gz | tar xzvf -
```